# vi unknown character @ symbol on multiple lines, can not delete or search

Tags: special-characters, vi

There is a character in vi that can not be seleted or deleted.

Should just be \r\n, but can not delete or search for the character

```
**$ od -bc ~/test.csv** 
  0000440   100 143 142 155 157 166 145 163 056 143 157 155 054 116 015 012
             @   x   x   x   o   v   e   s   .   c   o   m   ,   N  \r  \n
  0000460   103 101 122 101 126 101 116 122 105 056 103 117 115 054 107 145
             X   X   X   X   X   A   N   R   E   .   C   O   M   ,   G   e
```

In vi it looks like this

```
website,name,phone,email,office
XXXXX.COM,Bonnie XXXX,XXX-XXX-1386,no@email.com,N
XXXXX.COM,Terry XXXX,XXX-XXX-8888,willXXXX@XXXis.com,N
KAXXXXX.NET,Barbara XXXXXX,XXX-XXX-6184,no@email.com,N^MTHEXXXXXX.COM,Michael XXXXXXXX,XXX-XXX-1895,XXXXXX@xxxoves.com,N
@
@                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         @
@
@
... Repeats to end of page ...
@
XXXXXANRE.COM,Gerald XXXXXX,XXX-XXX-595
```

- Searching for /^Vx00 returns nothing
- Replacing null bytes does not remove it :%s/\%x00//g
- Trying to select it skips over all the "@" symbols to the next line
  XXXXXANRE.COM,Gerald XXXXXX,XXX-XXX-595
- :set list changes nothing, just adds $ before repeating "@"
- It is not standard "^@" null byte

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Open it with notepad++ ...maybe it's a hidden character

Comment: check this post https://superuser.com/questions/75130/how-to-remove-this-symbol-with-vim and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It means "If I were to display (and wrap) the next line, it would take more lines of text than are left on the screen to display it in.  I won't show you the truncated line, so you don't think that the truncated line is all there is."